# No boot menu on restart

Tags: boot, menu

I used Wubi to install ubuntu 12.10 but after restarting the computer I do not get a boot menu to start ubuntu.  Window starts automatically.  How do I get the boot menu?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using Boot-Repair tool. You can burn it on CD/DVD, or make USB bootable flash drive. It will fix it for you. You can find more information and download at the [official help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

I used it last week to fix completely broken Debian boot loader, and it fixed it without problems. It did not recognize Windows OS, but I resolved this after booting to linux and simply running `sudo update-grub`.

Other than that you can use [Ubuntu Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), but it will require some effort with mounting correct directories, chrooting and then fixing the boot.

Comment: It will not, since boot-repair don't know how to *"fix"* wubi.